# Memcached memory usage

Tags: memcached

Is there any command line or php script which returns the memcached total memory usage?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As **Mike** said, you can look at the line including the "STAT bytes" to see memory usage:

```
$ echo "stats" | nc -w 1 <host> <port> | awk '$2 == "bytes" { print $2" "$3 }'
```

Comment: Leaving that for future reference: The default host/port is: 127.0.0.1:11211

Comment: So just type in console: echo "stats" | nc -w 1 localhost 11211 | awk '$2 == "bytes" { print $2" "$3 }'

Comment: More verbose `echo "stats" | nc -w 1 localhost 11211 | awk '$2 ~ "bytes" { print $2" - "$3/1024/1024 " MB" }'`

Answer (score 19):

memcache's default port is 11211 so if memcache is local

```
telnet localhost 11211
```

Then run the stats command and that will spit out memory usage

```
stats
```

Comment: Thanks for the telnet tip, but what should I really read in there? I see STAT bytes 9857275
STAT curr_items 43599
STAT total_items 1048925 and I have the impression that my memcached is never filling up...

Comment: STAT bytes is the line you are looking for total usage

Answer (score 4):

I personally use PhpMemcacheAdmin

http://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/

It creates an easy to use GUI. Of course you'll need to have PHP support.

Comment: The site has moved to : http://blog.elijaa.org/phpmemcachedadmin-download-version-1-2-2/

Comment: Moved again to https://github.com/wp-cloud/phpmemcacheadmin :)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to answer @mike,

```
echo "stats" | nc localhost 11211
#or
echo "stats settings" | nc localhost 11211
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php:

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
echo $m->getStats()['localhost:11211']['bytes'];
```